# Working with a Pantone Guide in correlation with a well calibrated screen

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, color-profile, pantone

I have Dell XPS 15 9560 white led display, which is calibrated with an x-rite i1 Display Pro. I mainly do my work in Illustrator and I really want to get the best color accuracy for my designs. I have a Pantone Color Bridge Coated Guide and I am trying to understand how I should be using it in correlation with well calibrated screen. Let’s say I am working on a print document, where the color mode is set to CMYK (with the default North America General Purpose 2 color settings), and it seems to me that whatever Pantone Color I apply in .ai the colors look different on screen than the ones in the guide. Either more saturated, or darker, or the nuance a bit different. Is this normal? Am I making the right comparison? (or should I compare the Pantone value from the guide with the RGB value on the screen to see the same color). I am aware of the differences in color reproduction on screen vs on paper but I equipped myself with all these “color tools” in the hope that it will get me to a close as possible color resemblance on screen vs on paper and I want to know if my expectations are unrealistic or if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Computer screen always displays colours in RGB colourspace. It can't use other colourspaces such as CMYK or PMS - it just simulates them. Even when calibrated to perfection, you can only get so far with monitor backlit colour mixing of RGB colourspace.

Pantone colours are made using 18 different pigments, and some shades or tints simply can't be reproduced on computer screen - just simulated. That's why we use colour bridge that contains pantone to CMYK and to RGB values that should be as close (in terms of appearance) as possible - but there can and there will be differences.